# Port 3690 open from iexplore.exe

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, malware, visual-studio-2012

**BACKGROUND**

I was debugging my application in Visual Studio. I injected a dll into iexplore.exe, and starting visual studio remote debugger. My dll has the ability to check which ports are used by which process.

In the log of my application I saw that iexplore.exe has port 3690 running in it. This port is associated with SVN server.

I got very paranoid and haven't been coding with networking turned on for the past few days. My paranoia was that someone was stealing my code from my system as I was coding.

My host machine is OSX, my VM is running Windows 7 64-bit.

I read that most malware has Anti-VM features, and they avoid running in VMs. Also, I haven't pirated any software on my VM, all the software is bought directly from the vendor, or downloaded for free.

I have `CyberGhost VPN` free version running on the machine, aside from that and `Extreme Injector` (downloaded from `unknowncheats.me`) all the software I have is licensed/trusted.

**QUESTION**

Is it likely that port 3690 would be running from an `iexplore.exe` process while you are doing remote debugging with visual studio, and injected dll into `iexplore.exe`? Does Visual Studio open this port when remote debugging? Or is there a chance that my Parallels VM is infected with malware, or is my paranoia going too far?

**UPDATES**

I have MalwareBytes Anti-Malware running on the machine, but it is the free version.

Comment: Are you using any source control program with Visual Studio?

Comment: @DavidPostill Not that I know of, no. I'm working locally all the time, and this project is a startup supposed to be for commercial use so I'm not streaming it.